# div is getting the height of not is direct parent

Tags: css, height, parent, flexbox

I am facing a weird beahviour with Chrome only at the moment.

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="contacts">
    <div class="ui segment contacts-header"></div>
        <div class="contacts-content">
            <div class="table-wrapper">
                <div class="table-header"></div>
                <div class="table-inner-wrapper">
                    <table class="ui padded unstackable table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="five wide">
                                    <div class="th-inner first username">Name</div>
                                </th>
                                <th class="one wide">
                                    <div class="th-inner"><i class="star icon"></i></div>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <div class="th-inner">Status</div>
                                </th>
                                <th class="three wide">
                                    <div class="th-inner">Lists</div>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**LESS**

```
#contacts {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    .contacts-header {
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 2em;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
        flex-shrink: 0;
    }
    .contacts-content {
        overflow: auto;
        height: 100%;
        .table-wrapper {
            font-size: 0.85em;
            padding-top: 3.4em;
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
            .table-header {
                background-color: #F0F0F0;
                position: absolute;
                height: 3.4em;
                right: 0;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                z-index: 2;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #D4D4D5;
            }
            .table-inner-wrapper {
                overflow-x: hidden;
                overflow-y: auto;
                height: 100%;
                .table {
                    width: 100%;
                    border: 0;
                    margin: 0;
                    border-radius: 0;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
                    .th-inner {
                        position: absolute;
                        top: 0;
                        z-index: 3;
                        padding: 1em;
                        border-left: 1px solid #D4D4D5;
                        &.first {
                            border-left: none;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the div `.table-wrapper` is inheriting the height of the `#contacts` div istead of the height of its direct parent `.contacts-content`.

This break my layout since i am using `overflow-y: auto;` in `.table-inner-wrapper`, and of course the scrollbar never show because the `.table-wrapper` div have a bad height.

Let me show you the differences:

Chrome (buggy)
[image]

Firefox
[image]

Now just to show the weir behaviour, here was the size of the divs during the screen on Chrome:

- `.contacts`: 388px
- `.contacts-header`: 167px
- `.contacts-content`: 221px
- `.table-wrapper`: 388px
- `.table-inner-wrapper`: 348px

So, the `.table-wrapper` should have the height: 388 - 167 = 221px
When i manually set this height i get the expected visual, with the scrollbar.

[image]

**Note:** Just for the record, the code here is a table with a sticky header in pure css. I followed this : http://salzerdesign.com/test/fixedTable.html

Thanks

William

Comment: You can't nest elements in CSS. Is that LESS?

Comment: Yes it is, i will mention it in the subject, but it really doesn't matter here.

Comment: It just avoids confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After serious digging (no joking) i have found an answer.
This is a chrome bug which is detailled here : https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=341310

Last post gave me a lead : https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs/issues/28

I won't give code here since the explanation from **rinick** on the github issue is pretty clear.

In my case, i created a new wrapper before `.table-wrapper` with the following css:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
```